# Regular expression .Find it

Tags: regular-language, regular-expressions

Construct a regular expression that defines the language of all words that contain either the aa-substring or the bb-substring but NOT BOTH the aa-substring and the bb-substring in the same
word.Please tell me if  my answer is correct and if so is there a way to shorten it .Alphabet is{a,b} .So i assumed its a and b .
My answer is
((a+b)(aa*+bb*)(a+b))+(aa*+bb*)(a+b)+(a+b)(aa*+bb*)

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: (aa*+bb*)(a+b) accepts ab, therefore so does your regular expression.

Comment: See also [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).